# Let $G$ be a group with $|G|=455$. Show that $G$ is a cyclic group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a group with $|G|=455$. Show that $G$ is a cyclic group.

Answer (score 7):

It is well-known that if $n$ is a natural number, there is only one group of order n if and only if $\gcd(n,\varphi(n))=1$. Here $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function. For $n=455$ this applies. If there is only one group of a particular order it must necessarily be cyclic.

Comment: It is a nice result, and deserves to be better-known. I wonder whether OP is permitted to use it, or is instead required to get hands dirty with the specific number 455.

Comment: Dear, Nicky! I am interested in group theory and I have never met this fact before. Where could I find the readable proof of this result? Hope the proof is not so difficult.

Comment: @RFZ See [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Classification_of_cyclicity-forcing_numbers#.284.29_implies_.283.29), with $1.\Longleftrightarrow 5.$ and [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/148731/for-which-n-is-there-only-one-group-of-order-n). Try to google yourself for more references!

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I took a look at your link but as far as I realized it requires some knowledge about finite abelian groups, namely that any finite abelian group is the direct product of cyclic groups. And equivalence between (1) and (5) is proved through many intermediate steps

Comment: @RFZ This is why I said you should start searching yourself - because you know best what you will understand, and what you are willing to learn from new vocabulary - not us!

Answer (score 4):

Hints for you to prove. Let $\,G\,$ be a group of order $\,455=5\cdot 7\cdot 13\,$ ,then:

1) There exists one unique Sylow $\,7-\,$subgroup $\,P_7\,$ , and one single Sylow $\,13-\,$ subgroup $\,P_{13}\,$ , which are then normal;

2) There exists a normal *cyclic* subgroup $\,Q\,$ of order $\,91\,$

3) If $\,P_5\,$ is any Sylow $\,5-\,$ subgroup, then we can form the semidirect product $\,Q\ltimes P_5\,$

4) As the only possible homomorphism from a group of order $\,91\,$ to a group of order $\,4\,$ is the trivial one, the above semidirect product is direct .

Comment: Looks good, but surely there's a proof not reliant on Sylow?

Comment: Perhaps...is there?

Answer (score 0):

Let $|G|=pqr$ and WLOG $p<q<r$. Your case is the particular one for $p=5$, $q=7$ and $r=13$, where the fortunate conditions $p\nmid q-1$ and $p\nmid r-1$ and $q\nmid r-1$ take place, which allow the following counting argument.

By Sylow III, $n_p\mid qr$ and $n_p\equiv 1\pmod p$. So, $n_p=1,q,r,qr$ and $n_p=1+kp$. ***If*** $p\nmid q-1$ ***and*** $p\nmid r-1$, then $n_p\ne q,r$ and hence $n_p=1,qr$. Likewise, $n_q\mid pr$ and $n_q\equiv 1\pmod q$. So, $n_q=1,p,r,pr$ and $n_q=1+lq$. Now, $q\nmid p-1$ (because $q>p$); so, ***if*** $q\nmid r-1$, then $n_q\ne p,r$ and hence $n_q=1,pr$.

Suppose there are $qr$ $p$-Sylow subgroups ***and*** $pr$ $q$-Sylow subgroups. Since *all* these subgroups intesect pairwise trivially (they have order $p$ or $q$), their union's size amounts to $qr(p-1)+pr(q-1)+1$, which is greater than $pqr$$^\dagger$. Therefore, there isn't enough room in $G$ for so many $p$-Sylows ***and*** $q$-Sylows at the same time, and hence either $n_p=1$ or $n_q=1$.

If $n_p=1$, then the only $p$-Sylow is normal, say $H$. As such, $H$ is the union of conjugacy classes of $G$, with as many singletons as the order of $|H\cap Z(G)|$. But, by Lagrange, $|H\cap Z(G)|=1,p$, and the former option is ruled out because there aren't conjugacy classes (of sizes $p$, $q$, $r$ and their pairwise products) "filling the gap" $p-1$. Therefore $H$ is central, and being $G/H$ cyclic (as $q\nmid r-1$), then $G$ is abelian and finally cyclic (take the product of any three elements of order $p$, $q$ and $r$, respectively).

Same argument in case of $n_q=1$ (say $K$ the only $q$-Sylow, normal), with the only difference that now "filling non-centrally the gap" $q-1$ is prevented by the assumption $p\nmid q-1$, and the ciclicity of $G/K$ is ensured by $p\nmid r-1$.

---

$^\dagger$In fact: $qr(p-1)+pr(q-1)+1=$ $2pqr-r(p+q)+1>pqr\iff$ $pqr-r(p+q)+1>0$, which is true because $pqr-r(p+q)+1>$ $pqr-2qr+1=$ $qr(p-2)+1>0$.

Answer (score -3):

Notice $455 = 13*7*5$ and we know $13$, $7$ and $5$ are prime. Now use Lagrange theorem to show that G is cyclic. This is a hint.

Comment: Takes a bit more than Lagrange, doesn't it? I mean, there's no noncyclic group of order 35, but there is one of order 21.