# Group $G$ with $ord(G)=319$ is a cyclic group

Tags: proof-verification, finite-groups

> Let $G$ be a group with $ord(G)=319$. Proove that $G$ is a cyclic group.

Answer: $ord(G)=319=11*29=n$, the Euler's totient function gives $\phi(n)=\phi(11*29)=\phi(11)*\phi(29)=10*28$. Since $gcd(319,280)=1$, $G$ is a cyclic group.

[Related:[Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215282/let-g-a-group-with-show-that-g-is-a-cyclic-group/215548#215548) from Nicky Hekster]

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer especially the part . " If and only if ... " I do not understand you that you are trying to use in that step.


On the other hand , you can reach the result using that : Let $p$ and $q$ be primes such that $p>q$. If $q\equiv 1\mod p$, then every group of order $pq$ is isomorphic to the cyclic group $\Bbb Z/pq\Bbb Z$. (see Algebra by chapter III, proposition 6.1)

Comment: As ajotatxe pointed out: This "if and only if" assertion in your answer is false. In fact, there are cyclic groups of any positive integer order. Furthermore, the *existence* of a cyclic group of order 319 does not imply that *any* group of that order must be cyclic.

Comment: It is edited now.

Comment: Why does $\gcd(x, \phi x) = 1 \implies $ groups of order $x$ are cyclic?  Is that a theorem? if so which one?

Comment: In the link (comment from Nicky Hekster), stands that theorem.

Comment: Yes, but the question is just how "well-known" is it, and is the student asked to prove this expected to be able to cite or prove this result?  Citing "Nicky Hekter on the internet says this is a well known result" wouldn't be enough to convince me a student has understood and convinced him/herself that he/she understands why this is true?  Can you prove the result on your own?  Or can you cite a source where it is proven?  Furthermore, does this result have a name?

Comment: Good argument. Well I have no proof of it.

Comment: @carlosarturoHurtado But $q=11\not\equiv 1\mod p=29$?

Comment: @serge i have a mistake is $q\not\equiv 1\mod p$. sorry a lot.

Comment: which Algebra book you mean?

Comment: and do you mean $p>q, p \not\equiv 1\mod q$?

Comment: yes, sorry about that